# Determine the mnimum possible number of maximal independent sets in tree. Determine all the possible structure of a tree achieving the minimum number

Tags: graph-theory

I have a question about the below problems.

> Determine the minimum possible number of maximal independent sets in a tree.  Determine all the possible structure of a tree achieving the minimum number.

the minimum possible number of independent sets means that |{maximal independent sets in T}|? here |$A$| is a number of elements in the set $A$.

Comment: |{maximal independent sets in T}| is the size of an independent set, the number of maximal independent sets means counting the distinct independent sets. Maybe you are asking for the minimum size of a maximal independent set ?